# How can I show that the set of decimal representations of the natural numbers divisible by4 is regular?

Tags: automata

How can I show that the set of decimal representations of the natural numbers divisible by four is regular?
I'm stack on this problem. I tried some solutions but I know It is incorrect. Please help me.
If you use more details in your explanation, would be better.

Thank you"

I added a larger image of what I tried so far [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfzUI.jpg)

> Let $L$ be the language of natural numbers divisible by $4$. We want a DFA $M(L)=\{Z,\Sigma,\delta,z_A,E\}$ with $Z=\{z_A,z_S,z_R,z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3\}$ and $\Sigma=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ that recognizes $L$. $E=\{z_S,z_0\}$.
>
> $$\begin{array}{c|cc}
> \delta&z_A&z_S&z_R&z_0&z_1&z_2&z_3\\\hline
> r_0=0&z_S&z_R&z_R&z_0&z_2&z_0&z_2\\
> r_0=8,4&z_0&z_R&z_R&z_0&z_2&z_0&z_2\\
> r_1=9,5,1&z_1&z_R&z_R&z_1&z_3&z_1&z_3\\
> r_2=6,2&z_2&z_R&z_R&z_2&z_0&z_2&z_1\\
> r_3=7,3&z_3&z_R&z_R&z_3&z_1&z_3&z_1
> \end{array}$$
>
> $\delta:Z\times\Sigma:\langle z_i,r_k\rangle\mapsto z_j$ with $i\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $2i+k\equiv j\pmod 4$, $k,j\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, except that all words beginning with $0$ are thrown away ($z_R$) by the machine except the word $0$ itself, which is accepted by its own state $z_S$.
>
> We want to prove that each word $w$ over the alphabet $\Sigma$ that does not begin with $0$ takes the automaton $M$ to $z_i$ when $w\equiv i\pmod 4$. We prove this by induction on the length $n$ of $w$.
>
> When $n=1$ we have $$\begin{align*}&w=8,4\equiv 0\pmod4\implies z_0\\&w=1,5,9\equiv1\pmod4\implies z_1\\&w=2,6\equiv2\pmod4\implies z_2\\&w=3,7\equiv3\pmod4\implies z_3\end{align*}$$
>
> Our induction hypothesis is that the result holds for words of length $n$.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Yes, but it is written in german :(

Comment: I didn't draw a DFA, but i did some proofing: i konw that M(L) = {Z, Sigma, FunktionSymbol, Za, E} --- Sigma = {0, 1 ... 8, 9} --- Z ={Za, Zs, Zr, Z0, Z1, Z2, Z3}

Comment: @MiguelNuno: German is okay.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I added a image of what I have tried so far

Comment: @MiguelNuno: I’ve added a paraphrase of what’s in the image, but the image was a bit fuzzy in a few places, so you should check it, especially the subscripts in the transition table.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you

Answer (score 0):

A natural number whose decimal representation is $d_nd_{n-1}\ldots d_1d_0$ is divisible by $4$ if and only if the numbers whose decimal representation is $d_1d_0$ is divisible by $4$, since

$$d_nd_{n-1}\ldots d_200=100\cdot d_n\ldots d_2=4(25\cdot d_n\ldots d_2)\,.$$

It’s not hard to show that $d_1d_0$ is divisible by $4$ if and only if

- $d_1$ is even and $d_0\in\{0,4,8\}$, or
- $d_1$ is odd and $d_0\in\{2,6\}$.

You can do it with a DFA $M$ that has an initial state $z_e$ ($e$ for *even*) and just two other states, $z_{ea}$ ($ea$ for *even acceptor*) and $z_o$ ($o$ for *odd*). See if you can complete the transition table: it will have just three types of input. If you get stuck, leave a question for me.